# Kivy: How to clear screen?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I don't know this is a cache problem or not but i have a problem.

I have a button and function that calculates under over goals for teams
For example there are 5 results!
When i go back to homepage and reclick to calculate button than each time same results add to the result screen!
I want to clear this cache eachtime before calculation.
What is the problem here?
How can i fix this?

Thanks

1st click:

```
@ Team 1   Team2    Goals per Match    2.5     3.5

1 Arsenal Barcelona       2.25         under  under
2 Chelsea Ajax            3.25         over  under
3 Milan Juventus          4.25         over  over
4 Man.united Benfica       2           under  under
5 B.Munchen A.Madrid       2.25        under  under
```

2st click:

```
@ Team 1   Team2    Goals per Match    2.5     3.5

1 Arsenal Barcelona       2.25         under  under
2 Chelsea Ajax            3.25         over  under
3 Milan Juventus          4.25         over  over
4 Man.united Benfica       2           under  under
5 B.Munchen A.Madrid       2.25        under  under
1 Arsenal Barcelona       2.25         under  under
2 Chelsea Ajax            3.25         over  under
3 Milan Juventus          4.25         over  over
4 Man.united Benfica       2           under  under
5 B.Munchen A.Madrid       2.25        under  under
```

3st click:

```
@ Team 1   Team2    Goals per Match    2.5     3.5

1 Arsenal Barcelona       2.25         under  under
2 Chelsea Ajax            3.25         over  under
3 Milan Juventus          4.25         over  over
4 Man.united Benfica       2           under  under
5 B.Munchen A.Madrid       2.25        under  under
1 Arsenal Barcelona       2.25         under  under
2 Chelsea Ajax            3.25         over  under
3 Milan Juventus          4.25         over  over
4 Man.united Benfica       2           under  under
5 B.Munchen A.Madrid       2.25        under  under
1 Arsenal Barcelona       2.25         under  under
2 Chelsea Ajax            3.25         over  under
3 Milan Juventus          4.25         over  over
4 Man.united Benfica       2           under  under
5 B.Munchen A.Madrid       2.25        under  under
```

Some Py codes

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.metrics import dp
import requests
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior

        
class WrappedLabel(Label):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WrappedLabel, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.bind(
            width=lambda *x: self.setter('text_size')(self, (self.width, None)),
            texture_size = lambda *x: self.setter('height')(self, self.texture_size[1]))

class Tor(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Tor, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.status = True
        self.data = self.datas()
        self.Today = self.todayMatches()


    def homepage(self, s_image, screenmanager):
        
        if(screenmanager.current == 'underover_screen' or screenmanager.current == 'side_screen' or screenmanager.current == 'privacy_policy_screen'):
            screenmanager.transition.direction = 'right'
        screenmanager.current = 'homepage_screen'  

    def underOver(self, s_image, screenmanager):

        if(screenmanager.current == 'homepage_screen' or screenmanager.current == 'side_screen' or screenmanager.current == 'privacy_policy_screen'):
            screenmanager.transition.direction = 'left'
        screenmanager.current = 'underover_screen'



        print("""    
        Welcome to Under Over Goal Statics
        """)
        
        for i in range(len(self.Today[0])):

            # Some Calculations here #
            
            box = BoxLayout(size_hint_y = None, height = dp(50))
            sira = WrappedLabel(text = f'{i+1}', font_name = 'fonts/Lcd.ttf', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.10, 1), halign='center' )
            evsahibi = WrappedLabel(text = f'{self.Today[0][i]}', font_name = 'Roboto', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.225, 1), halign='center' )
            deplasman = WrappedLabel(text = f'{self.Today[1][i]}', font_name = 'Roboto', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.225, 1), halign='center' )
            macbasigol = WrappedLabel(text = f'{sonuc}', font_name = 'fonts/Lcd.ttf', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.15, 1), halign='center' )
            ust_2_5 = WrappedLabel(text = f'{predict2_5result}', font_name = 'fonts/Lcd.ttf', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.15, 1), halign='center' )
            ust_3_5 = WrappedLabel(text = f'{predict3_5result}', font_name = 'fonts/Lcd.ttf', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.15, 1), halign='center' )
            box.add_widget(sira)
            box.add_widget(evsahibi)
            box.add_widget(deplasman)
            box.add_widget(macbasigol)
            box.add_widget(ust_2_5)
            box.add_widget(ust_3_5)
            self.ids.gridsonuc.add_widget(box)

    def side(self, s_image, screenmanager):

        if(screenmanager.current == 'homepage_screen' or screenmanager.current == 'underover_screen' or screenmanager.current == 'privacy_policy_screen'):
            screenmanager.transition.direction = 'left'
        screenmanager.current = 'side_screen'

        print("""    
        Welcome to Winnig Side Statics
        """)

        for i in range(len(self.Today[0])):

            # Some Calculations here #

            box2 = BoxLayout(size_hint_y = None, height = 50)
            sira2 = WrappedLabel(text = f'{i+1}', font_name = 'fonts/Lcd.ttf', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.10, 1), halign='center' )
            evsahibi2 = WrappedLabel(text = f'{self.Today[0][i]}', font_name = 'Roboto', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.225, 1), halign='center' )
            deplasman2 = WrappedLabel(text = f'{self.Today[1][i]}', font_name = 'Roboto', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.225, 1), halign='center' )
            evkazanmasans = WrappedLabel(text = f'{homeWin}', font_name = 'fonts/Lcd.ttf', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.15, 1), halign='center' )
            beraberliksans = WrappedLabel(text = f'{draw}', font_name = 'fonts/Lcd.ttf', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.15, 1), halign='center' )
            deplasmansans = WrappedLabel(text = f'{awayWin}', font_name = 'fonts/Lcd.ttf', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.15, 1), halign='center' )
            box2.add_widget(sira2)
            box2.add_widget(evsahibi2)
            box2.add_widget(deplasman2)
            box2.add_widget(evkazanmasans)
            box2.add_widget(beraberliksans)
            box2.add_widget(deplasmansans)
            self.ids.gridsonuc2.add_widget(box2)



class BetApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Tor()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    BetApp().run()
```

KV codes

```
Tor:
<Tor>:
    ScreenManager:
        id: sm
        size: root.width, root.height
        Screen:
            name: 'homepage_screen'
            Image:
                source: 'images/homepage_background.png'
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: False
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: 1, 0.10
                Button:
                    id: underOver_button_homege
                    on_press: root.underOver(img_underOver, sm)
                    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0                 
                    Image:
                        id: img_underOver
                        source: 'images/underover_button.png'
                        allow_stretch: True
                        keep_ratio: False
                        size: self.parent.size
                        pos: underOver_button_homege.pos
                Button:
                    id: side_button_homepage
                    on_press: root.side(img_side, sm)
                    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0                
                    Image:
                        id: img_side
                        source: 'images/side_button.png' 
                        allow_stretch: True
                        keep_ratio: False
                        size: self.parent.size
                        pos: side_button_homepage.pos                   
        Screen:
            name: 'underover_screen'
            Image: 
                source: 'images/underover_background.png'
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: False
            BoxLayout:
                spacing: '20dp'
                orientation: 'vertical'    
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint: 1, 0.10
                    Label:
                        size_hint: 0.10, 1
                        text: '#'
                        font_name: 'fonts/Lcd.ttf'
                        font_size: '30dp'
                        color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1
                    Label:
                        size_hint: 0.225, 1
                        text: 'T1'
                        font_name: 'fonts/Lcd.ttf'
                        font_size: '30dp'
                        color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1
                    Label:
                        size_hint: 0.225, 1
                        text: 'T2'
                        font_name: 'fonts/Lcd.ttf'
                        font_size: '30dp'
                        color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1
                    Label:
                        size_hint: 0.15, 1
                        text: 'G.A'
                        font_name: 'fonts/Lcd.ttf'
                        font_size: '30dp'
                        color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1
                    Label:
                        size_hint: 0.15, 1
                        text: '2.5'
                        font_name: 'fonts/Lcd.ttf'
                        font_size: '30dp'
                        color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1
                    Label:
                        size_hint: 0.15, 1
                        text: '3.5'
                        font_name: 'fonts/Lcd.ttf'
                        font_size: '30dp'
                        color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint: 1, 0.80  
                    ScrollView:
                        bar_margin: '5dp'
                        bar_color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1 
                        bar_width: '5dp'
                        bar_inactive_color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1
                        GridLayout:                            
                            id: gridsonuc
                            cols: 1
                            spacing: '50dp'
                            size_hint_y: None
                            height: self.minimum_height        
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint: 1, 0.10
                    Button:
                        id: home_button_underOver
                        on_press: root.homepage(img_home, sm)
                        background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0                 
                        Image:
                            id: img_home
                            source: 'images/home_button.png'
                            allow_stretch: True
                            keep_ratio: False
                            size: self.parent.size
                            pos: home_button_underOver.pos
                    Button:
                        id: side_button_underOver
                        on_press: root.side(img_side, sm)
                        background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0                
                        Image:
                            id: img_side
                            source: 'images/side_button.png' 
                            allow_stretch: True
                            keep_ratio: False
                            size: self.parent.size
                            pos: side_button_underOver.pos         
        Screen:
            name: 'side_screen'
            Image:
                source: 'images/side_background.png'
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: False
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                spacing: '20dp'    
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint: 1, 0.10
                    Label:
                        size_hint: 0.10, 1
                        text: '#'
                        font_name: 'fonts/Lcd.ttf'
                        font_size: '30dp'
                        color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1
                    Label:
                        size_hint: 0.225, 1
                        text: 'T1'                        
                        font_name: 'fonts/Lcd.ttf'
                        font_size: '30dp'
                        color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1
                    Label:
                        size_hint: 0.225, 1
                        text: 'T2'
                        font_name: 'fonts/Lcd.ttf'
                        font_size: '30dp'
                        color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1
                    Label:
                        size_hint: 0.15, 1
                        text: 'H'
                        font_name: 'fonts/Lcd.ttf'
                        font_size: '30dp'
                        color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1
                    Label:
                        size_hint: 0.15, 1
                        text: 'D'
                        font_name: 'fonts/Lcd.ttf'
                        font_size: '30dp'
                        color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1
                    Label:
                        size_hint: 0.15, 1
                        text: 'A'
                        font_name: 'fonts/Lcd.ttf'
                        font_size: '30dp'
                        color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint: 1, 0.80  
                    ScrollView:
                        bar_margin: '5dp'
                        bar_color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1 
                        bar_width: '5dp'
                        bar_inactive_color: 1, 0.4, 0.769, 1
                        GridLayout:
                            id: gridsonuc2
                            cols: 1
                            spacing: '50dp'
                            size_hint_y: None
                            height: self.minimum_height    
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint: 1, 0.10
                    Button:
                        id: home_button_side
                        on_press: root.homepage(img_home, sm)
                        background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0                 
                        Image:
                            id: img_home
                            source: 'images/home_button.png'
                            allow_stretch: True
                            keep_ratio: False
                            size: self.parent.size
                            pos: home_button_side.pos
                    Button:
                        id: underOver_button_side
                        on_press: root.underOver(img_underOver, sm)
                        background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0                 
                        Image:
                            id: img_underOver
                            source: 'images/underover_button.png'
                            allow_stretch: True
                            keep_ratio: False
                            size: self.parent.size
                            pos: underOver_button_side.pos    
                  
        Screen:
            name: 'privacy_policy_screen'
            Image:
                source: 'images/privacy_policy_background.png'
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: False
```

Comment: Every time you press your button, you're creating a new BoxLayout widget and adding it (with `self.ids.gridsonuc.add_widget` or `self.ids.gridsonuc2.add_widget`) instead of updating the existing widget or destroying the previously-added widget(s).

Comment: Yes exactly. I am still looking for a solution for this.
I am new in Kivy and Python also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create method to clear all widgets from your screen and then add actual list of widgets. Possible implementation:

```
def init_screen(self):
    self.some_data_preparation() # if you need it
    self.refresh_my_screen()



def refresh_my_screen(self):
        """
        Method to remove all widgets from screen and add them again 
        :return:
        """
        widget_list = your_method_to_get_actual_list_of_widgets()
        self.ids.your_screen_id.clear_widgets() # remove all childs from this widget 
        for widget_id, widget_name, in widget_list:
            self.add_widget(
                widget_name=widget_name,
                widget_name=widget_name,
            )
```

Add init_screen() in kv file

```
<YourScreen>:
    name: root.manager.your_screen_name
    on_pre_enter: root.init_screen()
```

Example of real screen managment implementation you can find in many repos, for example:
https://github.com/Nuzhyn-Ivan/todo_list